# how to use pagetoken google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to write a list of all super admins and delegated admins in our google apps istance.

my script works fine, but it limits the result to 500 users as thats the limit google has, and google suggests to use pageToken for it, however am not sure how to it use.

Can anyone help me understand how do i use PageToken in following script-:

```
function getAdmins(){
var fileArray = [["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Admin Role"]]

  var optionalArgs = {"customer":"my_customer", maxResults: 500}  
  var allUsers = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs).users

  for (i=0; i<allUsers.length; i++){
  userDetails = allUsers[i]
  var fName = userDetails.name.givenName
  var lName = userDetails.name.familyName
  var pEmail = userDetails.primaryEmail
  var Admin = userDetails.isAdmin
  var dAdmin = userDetails.isDelegatedAdmin

  if (Admin === true) {
    Admin = "Super Administrator"
  }
    else if (dAdmin === true){
      Admin = "Delegated Administrator"
   }
    Logger.log(Admin)

    }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Admin Users")
  fileArray.push([fName, lName, pEmail,Admin]);

  Logger.log(fileArray) 



  sheet.getRange(1, 1, fileArray.length, 4).setValues(fileArray)


  }}
```

Comment: This [example code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users) does exactly what you want. In short, each call you make will return a nextPageToken(i.e. a token to identify the next page in result), which you need to include in the next call to get that page and so on.

Comment: thank you appreciate it, i want to learn how can i use that in the for loop or my script itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand pageToken you will need to understand the return value of (or response from)

```
 AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs)
```

This function returns a [reponse of the format](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#response):

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#users",
  "etag": etag,
  "users": [
    users Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

To access the user info you use the "users" key like so

```
var allUsers = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs).users
//below the same is written in two seperate lines
var page = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs)
var allUsers = page.users
```

As you can see from the response object you also have nextPageToken key, which defines what is the next page in the response, you grab this nextPageToken like so:

```
pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
```

Then you pass the pageToken to a new call to AdminDirectory like so:

```
var optionalArgs = {"customer":"my_customer", maxResults: 500, pageToken:   pageToken}  
          page = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs)
```

This will retrieve the next page on the search and also the nextPageToken, if any, for next page in the search. You make a recursive call until you don't have anymore pageToken.

The code below should do exactly that and was made by merging codes from [example code on google developer page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users) and the code written above by @GlodyArora. Literally just added a do while loop as mentioned in the example code.

```
function getAdmins(){
    var fileArray = [["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Admin Role"]]
    var pageToken, page;
     do {
      var optionalArgs = {"customer":"my_customer", maxResults: 500, pageToken:   pageToken}  
      page = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs)
      var allUsers = page.users

      for (i=0; i<allUsers.length; i++){
       userDetails = allUsers[i]
       var fName = userDetails.name.givenName
       var lName = userDetails.name.familyName
       var pEmail = userDetails.primaryEmail
       var Admin = userDetails.isAdmin
       var dAdmin = userDetails.isDelegatedAdmin

       if (Admin === true) {
         Admin = "Super Administrator"
       }else if (dAdmin === true){
         Admin = "Delegated Administrator"
       }
       Logger.log(Admin)
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Admin Users")
       fileArray.push([fName, lName, pEmail,Admin]);
      }
      pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
     }
     while(pageToken);
    Logger.log(fileArray) 
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, fileArray.length, 4).setValues(fileArray)
}
```

Hope it helps and clarifies things!